# Making  windows mobile 6 application forms generalized  to all resolution [480*640] and [320*320]?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a Windows mobile  6 application witch is designed for *480 x 640* VGA Resolution mobile.
Now the application is needed to install on *320*320 square Mobiles*...
I have some images for every form designed for *480*640* for banner image...
How can i make my application to adapt all resolution without changing all form design....?
and can i use the same image for square Device too ???

please help me on this.....

Handling Different Resolutions in Windows mobile app 6 in Visual Studio 2008 for .NET CF.
Can i use Same Forms to manage screen resolution and landscape/Portrait mode too...

please help with code or link to show me right way....

Comment: I have a Windows mobile  6 application witch is designed for *480 x 640* VGA Resolution mobile.
Now the application is needed to install on *320*320 square Mobiles*...
I have some images for every form designed for *480*640* for banner image...
How can i make my application to adapt all resolution without changing all form design....?
and can i use the same image for square Device too ???


please help me on this.....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MSDN has a number of articles that should help you on your way:

- [Adapt Your App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb264320.aspx) (vague overview)
- [Adaptable Apps For Windows Mobile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546609.aspx) explains various techniques for supporting dynamic screens
- The [Mobile Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480471.aspx) provides a pattern for helping with dynamic screens

Finally, [Windows Marketplace for Mobile: Certification Testing, Hopper, and Multiple Screen Support](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wmdev/archive/2010/02/18/windows-marketplace-for-mobile-certification-testing-hopper-and-multiple-screen-support.aspx) provides some fairly up to date information on the certificate requirements for the WM6 marketplace as they relate to dynamic screens.

Comment: I cant found any solution on this link...i ahev some image banner in every for...which is designed for 480*640 resolution...so while renedering this image in 320*320 screen device ...image is incomplete...